# How to control increasing data volume in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, amazon-athena

I have a data warehouse maintained in AWS Redshift. The data volume and velocity both have increased lately. One option is to keep scaling the cluster horizontally at the expanse of a higher cost of course. I was wondering if there are any archiving options available so that I can query the entire data as usual (maybe with a compromise in the querying time) but with a low or no additional cost?

One option would be to use external tables and query data directly from S3 but the tools used for achieving this, like Athena and Glue have their own cost, that too on a per query basis.

Comment: Athena/Glue/redshift spectrum = that is a great option.if you dont query that often and if you organise the tables correctly the costs can be minimal.

Comment: Not sure if you have already explored but there are `high disk and low computation` series of Redshift instance is also an option.

Comment: If you do not want to have per-query cost, you should try Presto. (Athena uses Presto's execution engine)

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Will Presto be as fast as Athena? I think to make it work fast, we'd have to keep large  clusters which again means additional cost. No?

Comment: If Athena stays up to date with Presto development, it will be as fast. It not, Presto can be faster. With greater power comes greater responsibility -- you may want to scale your clusters up & down. Of course, if you query from time to time only, it's not worth the effort and Athena's pay-per-query model will be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy options:

1. Ensure all tables have compression `SELECT * FROM svv_table_info;`.
2. Maximize compression by changing large tables to use `ENCODE zstd`.
3. Switch small tables < ~50k rows (depends) to `DISTSTYLE ALL` (yes this saves space!).
4. Switch from SSD based nodes (`dc2`) to HDD nodes (`ds2`) which have more 8x storage space.

Less easy options:

1. `UNLOAD` older data from Redshift to S3 and query using Redshift Spectrum.
2. Convert unloaded data to Parquet or ORC format using AWS Glue or AWS EMR and then query using Redshift Spectrum.

Please experiment with Redshift Spectrum. Query performance is typically very good and gets even better if your data is in a columnar format (Parquet/ORC).

Comment: Switching from DC2 to DS2 nodes helped!

Answer (score 1):

Data stored within Amazon Redshift will provide the highest performance.

However, if you have data that is less-frequently accessed, you could export (`UNLOAD`) it into Amazon S3, preferably as compressed, partitioned data and storing it as Parquet or ORC would be even better!

You could then use [Amazon Redshift Spectrum to Query External Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-using-spectrum.html) in Amazon S3. You can even join external data with Redshift data, so you could query historical information and current information in the one query.

Alternatively, you could use Amazon Athena to query the data directly from Amazon S3. This is similar to Redshift Spectrum, but does not require Redshift. Amazon Athena is based on Presto, so it is super-fast, especially if data is stored as compressed, partitioned, Parquet/ORC.

See: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Please note that Redshift Spectrum and Amazon Athena charge based upon the amount of data read from disk. Therefore, compressed, partitioned Parquet/ORC is both cheaper *and* faster.